# How to stop function execution on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a function that shows a slide with animated elements.

The click on $('.slider-wrapper') must hide the slide stop all the animations on it and bring them to the initial position.

I also use an animate.css library to animate some elements. When I hide the slide before animation complete and open it again, all the animations aren't running in order

How can I reset all the animations on slide close and start them from the begining on slide show?

```
$('.slider-wrapper').on('click', function(event){
  $(this).hide();
  $('video')[0].pause();
  clearTimeout(timer);
  $('.slide').stop(true, false).hide();
  $('.slide').find('*').removeClass('animated');
  $('.slide').clearQueue();
});

$('.a-1').on('click', function(){
  showSlide1();
});

function showSlide1() {
  var slide = $('#slide-1');

  slide.show().children().hide().delay(1000);
  slide.children('h1.center').delay(400).show(0).addClass('animated zoomIn');
  slide.children('h1 + p').delay(2500).show(0).addClass('animated zoomIn');
  slide.children('.img-1').delay(3000).show(0).addClass('animated zoomIn');
  slide.children('.img-2').delay(3500).show(0).addClass('animated zoomIn');
  slide.children('.img-3').delay(4000).show(0).addClass('animated zoomIn');
  slide.children('.img-4').delay(4500).show(0).addClass('animated zoomIn');
  slide.children('h2').delay(6000).show(0).addClass('animated zoomIn');
  slide.children('.minsk').delay(6500).show(0).addClass('animated slideInUp');
  slide.children('.lib').delay(7000).show(0).addClass('animated slideInUp');
}
```

Comment: Can include `html` ? , can create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net ? Tried `$('.slide, .slide *').stop(true, true)` ?

Comment: Here you are: http://nineseven.ru/html/mts-prezi/ . Click on the circle on the left side with "Идея" label to see the animation.

Comment: Does `$('.slide, .slide *').stop(true, true)` return expected results ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `$.finish()`

in this case `slide.finish()`, this should finish and apply all animations when used

check out the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/finish/
but I think this may be mainly for jquery .animate

alternatively for css animation you could try something like:

```
$("#slide-1").click(function() {    

 var el     = $(this),  
     newone = el.clone(true);

 el.before(newone);

 $("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove();

});
```

this will clone you attribute and replace it with a new one starting from the beginning.

another way with just JavaScript is:

```
var elm = this,
var newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
```

both of these should work with css animations.
However these are both rather simple ways of doing it. Hope they help!